# Balancing the heavy garage door by adjusting a torsion spring

Tags: garage-door

I installed Chamberlain MyQ MAX B970 w 1 1/4HP in one of two door garage about a year ago, and I've noticed recently that its motor has been making a harder than usual noise. Then, I checked the garage door balance and it was not balanced at all. It is heavy to lift open.  So I tried to adjust the balance by winding the torsion spring with torsion spring unwinding bars and a vice cramp locking the rod  as a tutorial video on the web.  I made 3 quarter turns but the door was not balanced (still heavy to open) so I was gonna make more turns but the spring would not turn.

My question is whether I am going right direction to wind.  I went from bottom to up in the image. Also, should I really force it to wind ?

[image: Torsion spring at the adjusting end]

Comment: Did the door's balance / rolling resistance change at all when you tightened it?  Is it hard to pull up but very easy to fall down, or is it stiff in both directions?

Comment: Was it balanced when you installed the motor? It's common for springs to weaken over time, but not that much. Are the cables still wound correctly? Is it binding at all?

Comment: I would also inspect the spring these can kill, very rare but serious injury is possible check everything prior to cranking on the spring.

Comment: As Ed Beal noted, these are dangerous, like crazy way out of proportion to how dangerous they look. Here is one video that I found that will give more information https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrUIN6hClB4

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica,   even If it changed anything,  I did not notice any changes at.  The door is just as heave to lift as before.

Comment: @isherwood, the door was not as heavyt but probably was not balanced as it should when I  installed the Chamberlain.  The cables wound correctly and it is binding. Having say that though, I don't know when this door was installed.  Considering how old this house is, it is probably time to replace it, though the spring looks still new.

Comment: @Ed Beal & Ack, I had seen these videos while I was researching how to balance the door.  Yeah, maybe it's time to call pro.

Comment: Yeah, you already said it's the same going up.  I'm asking about down, and the reason is I'm fishing for what the problem is.  Too-stiff going up usually means too-easy going down. If that's not so, then something is dragging, or something is broken, and it's not the spring at all.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica,  You are spot on.  I tried unwind as well wind the coil again but it would not move either ways.  I guess either the spring is busted or the rod inside the spring may be busted also.  Either ways, I have to call the garage repair guy.  Thanks for the suggestion.